# What is the *proper* differentiation between 来る and 行く?

Tags: word-choice, usage, vocabulary

In many beginning Japanese classes, 来る【くる】 and 行く【いく】 are presented as "to come" and "to go," respectively. Dictionaries generally also define them this way. However, every once in a while in more advanced classes, teachers will mention that this is not actually the case; these words are used differently in Japanese than their English (pseudo-)counterparts.

I cannot for the life of me remember the proper way to understand the differentiation between these verbs, past "come" and "go," a fact which is most embarassing.

Can someone please explain how these words are different than the English "come" and "go" in their usage?

Related question: [Difference between -ていく and -てくる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/676/384)

Comment: I'm curious to see how this is going to be answered... You can combine these verbs with a lot of things and they will not mean "to come" and "to go". But in their original form there's not much to say about 来る and 行く other than what you would say about their English equivalents...

Comment: I can only see 1 instance of 行く meaning "to come" but I will not explain it here.

Comment: @repecmps I'm actually only talking the verbs 来る and 行く used as such, not in other grammatical forms.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As usual, I'll *go* for examples which should *come* in handy.
Check the emphasized words. (The translations are not natural, but it's not the point here.)

***Sample 1***

> Won't you come visit *me* in France?
>   フランスに来ませんか？待っていますよ！
>
> Yes, I will go *to France*. We will go see the Arc de Triomphe.
>   はい、フランスに行きますよ。一緒に凱旋門を見に行きましょう。
>
> Great. Mark came last summer already.
>   良かった。去年の夏はマークさんが来たよ。

***Sample 2***

> Will you come/go to *John*'s party tonight?
>   今晩、ジョンさんのパーティに行きますか？
>
> No, I won't go to *John*'s.
>   いいえ、行きません。
>
> Paul is not coming/going either.
>   ポールさんも行きません。

***Sample 3***

> Come here!
>   来てください!
>
> Yes sir! I'm coming right away.
>   はい、すぐ行きます。

***Summary***

Tarou is at place A, Jun is at place B. Tarou calls motions towards A as "来る". Tarou calls motions away from A as "行く". Tarou calls motions towards Jun as "行く".

行く/来る is from-here/to-here relatively to the person who uses the verb now. 
(I suddenly have a doubt for a situation like "will you visit me at my new home *when I moved to France*". I think "来る" would still be good, because it's still about the narrator being reached.)

Comment: ok but how is it different from other languages?

Comment: Well, suppose you're talking about a great party that everyone knows about. You'll tell your British friend "are you coming tonight?", but (I think) that you would never tell your Japanese friend "来ますか？". You'll have to say "行きますか", as you're not the host.

Comment: In English you're asking "are you coming tonight" because you anticipate your presence there or because it implies "come with us". I think that would work in Japanese as well?

Comment: @repecmps: I don't know... I feel like it would be 一緒に行く？ in that case -- but I *did* think of an example in English: "Can I come over to your house?"

Comment: @rep: both I think.

Comment: @rintaun: I said it implies "come with us", not that it's a translation for it. Anyway "俺たちパーティ行く、お前来ないのか？" 来る works. As for "come over" it's a question for EL&U. Japanese takes 来る and 行く literally and it means come and go.

Comment: @Axioplase, that should be はい、フランスに行きますよ. If the question were 来ないのですか, いいえ would be correct.

Answer (score 7):

As Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams says, the key is the difference in point of reference. So when the first and the second person's perspective are the same, Japanese and English have the same distinction for these words. Difference between Japanese and English appears when the first and the second person's perspective are different. That is typical when someone is calling another. A different famous example is the words said at sexual climax. In English, people say `I'm coming`. This is in second person's perspective. In Japanese, people say `行く`. This is in first person's perspective.

Answer (score 6):

「来る」 implies motion or action towards or ending at the speaker or the speaker's current situation, whereas 「行く」 implies motion or action away from or beginning at the speaker or the speaker's situation.

Comment: This seems to be the same as the English usage of the words "come" and "go," unless I'm misunderstanding something...

Comment: In English, "come" and "go" can also be used with the listener as a point of reference.

Comment: To elaborate: in English you can say "I'll come over there", but in Japanese this is grammatically impossible because "come" implies you're there already, so the correct verb is 行く.

Answer (score 1):

There are many cases where the Japanese "KURU/KIMASU" really means the same as the English "come", and the Japanese "IKU/IKIMASU" really means the same as the English "go", but there's a certain case where it's used differently.
Let's look at the following 4 scenarios.

This video explains with animations:
[I'll come or I'll go?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vpKPOrjuMcg&ab_channel=ShiroNekoJapanese)

Basically,

> KURU/KIMASU - Someone or something is moving toward you or whoever the speaker is
>
> IKU/IKIMASU - Someone or something is moving AWAY from you or whoever the speaker is. When you are the speaker, you will still be moving away from yourself(the speaker) or your current position by "going somehwere"

### Scenario 1:

In this scenario, you are talking with A about "B coming" to you (B moving toward you). In English, you'd say "B comes" because B is moving toward the speaker, which is you, the white cat in the picture. It's the same thing in Japanese, so you'd call B's action as "KIMASU" because B is moving toward the speaker.
[image: You are talking with A about B coming toward you]

### Scenario 2:

In this scenario, you are talking with A about A's action. In English, you'd ask "Will you come?" because you want to know whether A will be coming toward you, the speaker (the white cat in the picture). It's the same thing in Japanese, so you'd call A's action as "KIMASU" because A is moving toward the speaker.
[image: You are talking with A about A coming toward you]

### Scenario 3:

In this scenario, you are talking with A about you going to the third person, B. You are moving away, so you'd tell A "I'll go (to B)" in English. Again, it's the same thing in Japanese, you are moving away from the speaker, which is yourself, the white cat in the picture, so you'd call your own action as "IKIMASU"
[image: You are talking with A about you going to B]

### Scenario 4:

In this scenario, you are talking with A about you going to A. In English, "come" is used when you are moving toward the person you are talking to, so you'd say "I'll come (to you)". BUT, in Japanese, it doesn't matter where you are moving to. It doesn't matter that you are moving toward the person you are talking to. `As long as you are moving away from the speaker, which is yourself, the white cat in the picture, you'd call your action as "IKIMASU"`.
[image]

Hope this helps.