# When do you use forms of 歩く as a verb to talk about walking?

Tags: grammar, verbs, word-usage, subsidiary-verbs

I've come across different usages of 歩く as a verb and was unsure in which scenarios they would be most appropriate to use.

Is 歩く used with 来る?

> 東京タワーまで歩いて来ます。

Or is it used with 行く?

> 東京タワーまで歩いて行きます。

Or is it just used on its own?

> 東京タワーまで歩きます。

What's the difference between these three?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-ていく and -てくる are [subsidiary verbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18952/5010) that can attach to almost any verb. They can safely attach to 歩く, too.

- [Difference between -ていく and -てくる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/676/5010)

-ていく/-てくる are very common and important in Japanese. Practically speaking, 歩きます without -ていく/-てくる may sound unnatural in many cases, unless you want to emphasize the method of going/coming.

When you feel like using -てくる, be sure to keep [this rule](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1669/5010) in mind, too. 東京タワーまで歩いて来ます is used only when the speaker is already at or near Tokyo Tower.