# Verbs +「~てくる」 , which verbs?

Tags: grammar, usage, verbs, て-form

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between -て行く and -て来る](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/676/difference-between-and)

my doubt is which verbs I can use with ~てくる (~ていく)

ABOUT ME
I don't want to say "I undestand", but I'd like to say "I'm understanding" (I'm becoming to understand)

> わかってきました。
>   わかるようになってきました。

(what is the difference?)

ABOUT OTHERS
"She's becoming to understand it"

マリさんは...

> わかってきたそうです。
>   わかるようになってきました。

(what is the difference?)

Maybe first it's important to know the possibilities of てくる (ていく). How can I know which verbs I can use ～ようになってくる and/or just ～てくる. Is there much difference between them?

- あの店、昼間　開くようになってきました。
- あの店、昼間　開いてきました。
- あの店員はドアを開けるようになってきました。
- 彼はやせるようになってきましたね。
- 彼はやせてきましたね。
- バイトをやめたときから、テレビを見るようになってきました。
- バイトをやめたときから、テレビが見れるようになってきました。
- 雨がやんできます。
- 雨がやむようになってきます。
- 今からカメラは安くなっていきます。
- 今からカメラは安くなってきます。

sorry if my examples are wrong, I just created them while I was writing.
japanese is really interesting, but really difficult.
hope you could understand my doubt. and please, give examples!
よろしく thanks

Answer (score 7):

The general idea is

> - てくる: The action/change is coming toward your territory/perspective.
> - ていく: The action/change is going away from your territory/perspective, or is moving in a direction irrelevant to you.

- 高くなります/高くなりました

  > - Suppose you are on the roof of a building, observing down on a high tide gradually rising toward you
  >
  > > 高くなってきます。
  > >     高くなってきました。
- Suppose you are observing from far away a high tide gradually rising, or you are in the bottom of a sea (perhaps in a wet suit) looking up the clear water rising
      高くなっていきます。
      高くなっていきました。

About me

> - When you are in the very process of understanding
>
> > 分かってきました。
> >     分かるようになってきました。

When you are retrospecting how you came to understand
    分かっていきました。
    分かるようになっていきました。

About others

> - In a first person narration
>     分かってきました
>     分かるようになってきました。
> - In a third person narration
>     分かっていきました
>     分かるようになっていきました。
> - Indirect report
>     　分かってきたそうです。
>     △ 分かっていったそうです。

Comment: can say that わかっていきました is past ("progressive"), and わかってきました is the present ("progressive")?

Comment: @danieltomio No. They are both past progressive. You should not confuse syntactic forms with their meaning.

Comment: but talking about meaning, the first one is about what it's in the past? and the last one is my state in the present?

Comment: @danieltomio When you are talking about tense, you are talking about grammatical forms. た is clearly the past tense marker (or, according to alternative views, it is an aspect (perfect) marker). In English, `If I were, ...` is subjunctive past, and it can express things about present.