# Translating ならば受け止めて行くまでさ word for word

Tags: usage, translation

I'm going for a word-for-word translation of [(miss) understood](http://www.jpopasia.com/lyrics/1980/ayumi-hamasaki/miss-understood.html) (you can hear the song [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NcQuCkJ0HVs), but I'm having trouble with the verse:

> 今さらきれい事だなんて
>
> 聞くつもりも言うつもりもない
>
> 痛みは増える一方だろう
>
> ならば受け止めて行くまでさ

Basically what I got out of google translate was

> Beautiful words I too late
>
> Not even going to say going to hear
>
> While the pain will increase
>
> Sa to take if we

Which I reworked, with help from JpopAsia to (I have trouble with Japanese characters, so I am using transliteration right now)

> Imasara (too late) kirei gotoda (beautiful words) nante (for me)
>
> Kiku (listen) tsumori (going to) mo iu (a.k.a.)
>
> tsumori (going to) mo nai (not)
>
> Itami (pain) wa fueru (increase)
>
> i-ippou (on the other hand) darou (would be)
>
> Nara ba (if) uketomete (accept)
>
> iku (go) made (to) sa (sa=emphasis)

I get the meaning of every sentence except the last one.  It is something like this right now:

> If accept, go to !!

But I don't understand what "go to" (followed by `sa` for emphasis) could mean in this context.

Answer (score 4):

ならば～ = In which case, ~.

This use of いく following the te-form is explained in [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/676/difference-between-%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%8F-and-%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8B).

And as for ～まで, its nuance of "up to (a point)" is still present in this usage, **Vするまでだ**, meaning "(I will do / I need to do) **up to** V (and nothing at all further).", which in this case can be interpreted as "It's merely a matter of V'ing."

It is also seen after other tenses like the past-tense, **Vしたまでだ**, meaning "(I did) **up to** V (and nothing at all further)", i.e. "All I did was V / I merely V'ed."

> 君が来てほしいというから来たまでだ. I just came because you asked me to.

---

I think this is about the right amount of detail for an answer (which I wrote in case other people would find it helpful). I can't provide more without considering this as a "translation question".

Also, to be clear, you misunderstand many other things here; I would say that your breakdown shows that you do not understand any of the sentences. This approach of relying on Google Translate is doomed to failure.