# Question about 〜なら〜までだ

Tags: grammar, meaning

In a Japanese to English dictionary, I found this description for まで:

> (only when used in a sentence with the なら
> conditional prior to it) changes the sentence to become similar to using 〜たら

Is this accurate? And if so, what does that even mean?

I did come across an example of this in the following sentence:

> 命令**なら**、従う**まで**だ。

Comment: Dup? [Understanding "電車がないなら、歩くまでだ。"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/97977)

Comment: Is this from an online dictionary? Do you have a link? ～なら～までだ is indeed a sentence pattern worth memorizing, but I'm not sure how it relates to たら.

Comment: And なら is not even a necessary part of the construct. まで plays the same function in 命令され**たら**、従うまでだ or 命令であれ**ば**、従うまでだ。

Comment: It's from an online dictionary called Kireicake. I installed it into a mousover dictionary program called Yomitan, so I don't have a link unfortunately. However, after looking at another forum just now, it seems like Kireicake has inaccurate definitions at times. Given that and the responses here, I think it's best to discard that dictionary.