# Meaning of auxiliary ゆく/いく in this context

Tags: translation, nuances, subsidiary-verbs

While translating a song, I've stumbled upon the following sentence:

> 落ちた希望を拾って明日に繋いでゆけば

---

Which got me wondering what the difference between the following two is:

> 1. 落ちた希望を拾って明日に繋いでゆけば
> 2. 落ちた希望を拾って明日に繋げば

I have a feeling that the first sentence includes a sense of "doing continually from now" [based on what I've read earlier,](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/676/difference-between-%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%8F-and-%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8B%20%22based%20on%20what%20I%20read%20earlier.) but I am rather unsure.
Is there a possible meaning which  I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like you say, 繋いでいく has a sense of progression, i.e. the process of "connecting to tomorrow" is intended to be continued (connecting tomorrow to the day after tomorrow, etc.).

The counterpiece to ~ていく is ~てくる, meaning that something has been continued until now.

Some phrases

> 頑張ってきた
>   I have been giving my best (all this time).
>
> 楽しんでいこう
>   Let's have fun (from now onwards).

I don't know of any English construction that would correspond well to this sense of progression from present into the future (～ていく) or from the past into the present (～てきた）.

Comment: I hope you don't mind me asking this here, but I felt it was undeserving of another question.
Within the right context, can -いく also mean "to do up until now, and continuing to do", or is the starting point of the action **locked** to the present?

Comment: No, it is not locked to the present. The focus is on its continuing into the future. Similarly, ～てきた doesn't mean it has to end in the present.