# Question regarding も and ごめんだ

Tags: grammar, translation

I’m trying to understand the following sentence:
この世界に生きて命を惜しいと思ったことなど一度もないが、訳も分からずやられるのはごめんだ

I don’t have any context as this is the first sentence in the story.

Splitting the sentence and parsing it:

> この世界に生きて命を惜しいと思ったことなど一度もないが
>
> この世界に生きて命 – Living life in this world
>   惜しいと思ったことなど – Felt disappointed with things like
>   一度もない – Not once
>
> I’ve never once felt disappointed with life in this world
>
> 訳も分からずやられるのはごめんだ
>
> 訳 – Reason
>   分からず – Without knowing
>   やられる – was done/given to
>   ごめんだ – ???
>
> The reason also(?) without knowing what was done is ???

My questions are:
1. Does も mean “also” or something else in the second part of this sentence?
2. Does の in のは turn 分からずやられる into a noun like explained [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12024/22593)?
3. What does ごめんだ mean here?  Online dictionaries give ごめん as sorry, your pardon, declining or dismissal but none of them seem to fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> この世界に生きて命を惜しいと思ったことなど一度もないが、訳も分からずやられるのはごめんだ

この世界に生きて＝この世界に生まれてから＝この世界に生きている間で＝for my life in this world, since I was born in this world

やられる＝the colloquial expression for 殺される＝being killed

ごめんだ＝御免だ＝御免である＝嫌だ、嫌である（嫌で拒否する気持ちを表す語）

***I have never been afraid of death for all my life in this world, but I do not want to be killed without even knowing the reason.***

> My questions are:
>   1. Does も mean “also” or something else in the second part of this sentence?
>   2. Does の in のは turn 分からずやられる into a noun like explained here?
>   3. What does ごめんだ mean here? Online dictionaries give ごめん as sorry, your pardon, declining or dismissal but none of them seem to fit.

Answer to your questions:

1. 訳もわからず is a set phrase, meaning "even without knowing why." You had better think the も is different from "also" in this context, and it is not related to the second part. You may just remember "訳も分からず" as a set phrase. You can think the も as "even" in this context.
2. Exactly.　訳も分からずやられる**の**＝訳も分からずやられる**事**＝**to** be killed without knowing why.
3. The ごめん is different from "sorry" in this context. ごめんだ means "I want to avoid ~~ing."

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, your parsing of the first sentence is a bit off.

「生き/て」and「命」 does not connect. The first sentence includes 「命が惜しい」(or 「命を惜しいと思う」) which means "(one's) life is dear," or even better, "one doesn't want to die."
So the correct parsing will be:

> この世界に生きて/「命を惜しい」と思ったことなど/一度もないが

and the translation

> Living in this world, I have never wanted not to die, but...

(very free translation):

> Living in this world, I have always risked my life for anything, but...

---

Now about your question:

> Does も mean “also” or something else in the second part of this sentence?

It doesn't quite mean "also." I believe this も's closest meaning is "even." So '訳も分からず' translates to

> Not knowing even the situation
>
> Does の in のは turn 分からずやられる into a noun like explained here?

Yes, but it modifies all the previous words. (from "訳も" to "やられる")

> What does ごめんだ mean here? Online dictionaries give ごめん as sorry, your pardon, declining or dismissal but none of them seem to fit.

See the entry for ごめん(御免) [here.](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/82251/meaning/m0u/) The third meaning is the best fit. It says "the word to express rejection in disgust." 「----は御免{ごめん}だ」 simply means "I never want {sth / to do sth} / I'll have none of sth / I've had enough of sth."

And for the look of things, 'やられる' probably means 'being defeated.'

So the translation should be:

> I never want to be defeated without knowing even the situation.

Comment: This was a well set-out explanation which made everything really easy to understand, but Seesawscene’s answer was more accurate after going deeper into the story.