# What does きた do in this sentence

Tags: grammar, nuances, time, anime

What is the difference between

> 中学生になってもずっとボーッと**生きてきた**けど

> 中学生になってもずっとボーッと**生きた**けど

What does **きた** do in this sentence this is from the second episode of the anime *K-On!* the character is telling a story about her school life I don't see what **きた** does in the sentence.

Comment: Related: 1. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/676 2. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3160 3. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18521 4. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55192

Answer (score 2):

It adds the sense that the action/state of the preceding verb (生きる) has continued till now.

If you want to say you will continue living that way into the future, you can say ずっとボーッと生きていく.

Comment: is this the same きた as in くる or is it something else

Comment: @k-onfan: It's the same きた as [来る]{くる} ("to come").  It's from the idea that the action "**has come** into the present moment".  Likewise, the いく for "continuing into the future" is the same as [行く]{いく} ("to go"), from the idea that the action "**will go** further on from the present moment".

Comment: @k-onfan: It’s the same, but it is usually written in hiragana in these compound forms. That’s also true for いく and other basic verbs that form compound verbs, such as みる (as in 食べてみる) and おく (as in 開けておく).