# What's きます in 持ってきます?

Tags: verbs

What does きます mean here? Also I'd like a translation for this sentence.

女の子達は両親に朝御飯を**持ってきます**。

Comment: 持ってくる｛もっている｝ is often considered its own verb meaning "to bring."  Please see the following for a better treatment of how ～てくる and ～ていく affect verb meaning in general: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/676/difference-between-%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%81%8f-and-%e3%81%a6%e3%81%8f%e3%82%8b

Comment: Another useful post that explains ～てくる and ～ていく in the past.http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/25505/whats-the-difference-between-%e6%ad%a9%e3%82%93%e3%81%a7%e3%81%84%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f-and-%e6%ad%a9%e3%82%93%e3%81%a7%e3%81%8d%e3%81%9f/25564#25564

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**持って来ます** is some sort of compound verb, and as many of these verbs it is best understood when reading it's conforming verbs in sequence.

1. 持って来ます.
2. 持つ & 来る.
3. take/have & come.
4. **Finally we understand it is the transitive verb:** to bring.(because you take something and come someplace)

There are a lot of this kind of words and you can even make your own as needed:

**て-verb1 + verb2**.

e.g. 傘を忘れて出かけました。 I forgot my umbrella and left(without it).

Answer (score 0):

きます comes from the verb 来る (to come).

```
女の子達は両親に朝御飯を持ってきます。
```

=    The girls will come and bring breakfast to the parents.

Comment: @virmaior why do you downvote my answer?

Comment: I did not downvote your answer... I did edit your answer a few hours ago.

Comment: @virmaior Oh, OK! Sorry!