# What does kimashita means in 寒くなってきました

Tags: grammar

> 寒くなってきました

I learned the grammar "verb-te + ikimasu/kimasu" which means doing something and going back or the other. I searched up the grammar and it also means "becoming/start to". 寒くなって already means becoming cold. What does kimashita mean in the sentence above?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/25505/whats-the-difference-between-%e6%ad%a9%e3%82%93%e3%81%a7%e3%81%84%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f-and-%e6%ad%a9%e3%82%93%e3%81%a7%e3%81%8d%e3%81%9f / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/676/difference-between-%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%81%8f-and-%e3%81%a6%e3%81%8f%e3%82%8b

Answer (score 1):

Both answers that the previos two users replied are correct I think.

To confirm which meaning this sentence implies, we would need more context. Like for example:

If the sentence looked like this
最近、寒くなってきましたね
Then that means that recently it started getting cold.

However, if it were like this
冬に入ってから、だんだん寒くなってきました
Then it would imply a gradual slow change.

Without context, it could mean any of these meanings.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best English interpretation is "It has started to get cold."

The state of becoming cold has come.

Answer (score 0):

It means, "it's been getting colder and colder (from the past) until now".
On the other hand, 寒くなっていきます means "it will get colder and colder from now on".