# Meaning of いって in しっかりしていって

Tags: meaning, parsing

I have trouble fully understanding what's the role of いって in this sentence:
リノンのことだけはしっかりしていってくれればと思うけど。

To give it a bit background, this is what Konoha from 月が導く異世界道中 is thinking about Rinon, the younger sister of Toa. Regarding Toa, he thinks just before the sentence in question:
もう一度荒野を目指そうとしても僕には何も言えないけどね
(Toa being an adventurer, but a bit irresponnsible towards her sister, so Konoha likely worries about Toa's younger sister)

If  いって comes from 行く　I'd translate it as "I just hope that Rinon('s situation) will be OK."

(following this reasoning here: [Difference between -ていく and -てくる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/676/difference-between-%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%81%8f-and-%e3%81%a6%e3%81%8f%e3%82%8b?noredirect=1&lq=1) and here [What's the difference between 歩んでいった and 歩んできた?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/25505/whats-the-difference-between-%e6%ad%a9%e3%82%93%e3%81%a7%e3%81%84%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f-and-%e6%ad%a9%e3%82%93%e3%81%a7%e3%81%8d%e3%81%9f))

If that shouldn't be a case, I'm at a loss from which verb this いって is derived.

Thanks!

Comment: In terms of usage, it's the same as the linked questions, but more contexts are necessary to make sense of リノンのことだけは.

Comment: In the linked questions 行く is used as a helper verb. In the sentence in question it could be used as a stand-alone verb like しっかりして（から）行ってくれれば. At least that's how I would read it in the given context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment section, this ていく could be either of the following depending on the context.

1. Simply "and then go":

   > I hope you at least take care of Rinon **before leaving here**.
2. A subsidiary verb that adds a sense of "gradually over time from now":

   > I hope you'll **eventually** learn to take care of Rinon, at least.

Does the speaker know Toa is planning to go somewhere (e.g., on another adventure) in the near future? If so, the first interpretation is correct. Otherwise, the second interpretation is possible, but I feel it's less likely.

The literal meaning of (Xについて)しっかりする is something like "make sure (about X)". Since you said the speaker is worrying about Rinon, I used "take care".