# How to use だんだん properly?

Tags: grammar, expressions, adverbs

If I wanted to say, "Ken's getting better and better at Japanese", then would this be correct?

> けんさんはだんだんじょうずになります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage of だんだん is just fine. It's a standalone adverb which can be used without any other particle. An adverb is usually placed just before what it modifies (in this case, じょうずになる).

---

You have to use the progressive form of なります; otherwise the sentence would mean "Ken gets (or will get) better and better at Japanese".

> けんさんはだんだん日本語【にほんご】が上手【じょうず】になっています。

To make this a bit more natural, you can add a subsidiary verb [～てくる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/676/5010) and say:

> けんさんはだんだん日本語が上手になってきています。

Comment: Based on the first part of your answer, which is more "natural"? `けんさんはだんだん日本語が上手になってきています。` or `けんさんは日本語がだんだん上手になってきています。`

Comment: @DaBest Both sound equally natural to me. 日本語 is not something that can be modified by an adverb, so this だんだん unambiguously modifies 上手になる.