# きている in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

『毒触手草』に気をつけること。歯が生えてきている最中ですから。

Comment: So... what's your question?

Comment: already answered.

Comment: For the meaning of ～てくる, this thread might be of help: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/677/9831

Comment: @Narutokage The community still decides whether this question should be left open based on the quality on the question. So even if you have found your answer, you may want to improve the presentation of your question for the benefit of future readers.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a standard -てくる formation combined with -ている to express that it's a continuing process. This might seem awkward in the abstract, not so much when you think about context. 「歯が生える」 means that "teeth are growing." Conceptually speaking, teeth aren't a part of you (at least as teeth) until they grow in, so adding on a -てくる to this makes the nuance more along the lines of "teeth grow in[to one's mouth]." -ている here just means that the process is continual, so "teeth are growing in." Putting it all together, you get something along the lines of "Be careful of the Venomous Tentacula. Its teeth are coming in."

Since I had no idea what a 毒触手草 was I did a quick Google search and found some Harry Potter thing. Googling *that* along with "teeth" led me to [this](https://www.pottermore.com/quote/teething-problems) page, so if you have similar questions in the future I'd recommend digging around on Google for a bit since Pottermore is pretty popular.

Comment: Your answer is really delightful . -てくる has always given me a puzzle since the day I learn Japanese. The concept of "teeth aren't a part of you until they grow in" is a very new to me. I need to note it in my book.