# What does 白く濁っていく mean?

Tags: translation, song-lyrics

Reading the [lyrics](http://lyrics.jetmute.com/viewlyrics.php?id=2252845) of the song [化粧直し](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ezC4ybLJsPM) by 東京事変 the first sentence says:

貴方が去ったあとのこの部屋　白く濁っていく

So I translate that to:

You left after this room  白く濁っていく

What do 白く濁っていく means?

Comment: Do you know what 濁{にご}って means?  What's your attempt at how to translate this?  It's poetic language for sure.  It's how the room appears after "you" left the room.

Comment: I just noticed that your translation of 貴方が去ったあとのこの部屋 is only a literal word-for-word translation ignoring that Japanese word order differs from English.  貴方が去ったあとのこの部屋="The room after you'd left".

Comment: Questions asking for translations are off-topic unless prior research effort is clearly indicated; we're here to help you learn, not provide a bulk translation service.

Comment: Realted (in case you're having trouble with the ～ていく form): https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/676/9831

Comment: It's up to the study level that often times learners have no idea how to look at it at all.

Comment: 学習者が初心者で全く何もわからないといった場合には、翻訳依頼はoff-topicだというサイトのルールも無視していい、翻訳‌​もしてあげればいい・・・ということにはならないと思います

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does 白く濁っていく mean?

I find 濁っていく is the Japanese way to express progressive aspect.

濁{にご}る is the base form.
濁っている expresses the ***state***; this can't mean progressiveness to us, native speakers.
濁っていく expresses the ***progression***.

It's like clear water gradually gets milky when added with some white paint.

> 貴方が去ったあとのこの部屋　白く濁っていく

The particle の is making the phrase 貴方が去ったあと an adjective to modify この部屋. It's a creative expression, and we don't usually say things in this way, but it's nicely said as lyrics. So, it's saying "this room that is (in the condition) of after 'you' have left."

Although it's natural to read the two lines as the former is the subject and the latter is the predicate, without a particle between them, the two lines are not really connected to each other. This is possible because of the poetic license.

Comment: Nice explanation, but I think the OP also wishes to understand what 白く濁る could mean in this context.  I very much like your example of white paint added to water, but in terms of the atmosphere in the room (立ち去れた部屋の雰囲気) how would you translate this?

Comment: I'm afraid I've already explained that as far as for the provided context. Also this is poetry. I've tried to provide as much information as possible for non-native learners to understand the literal meaning of the words, at the same time not to go too much into my own interpretation for the OP and other readers to enjoy it. A grammar point that I should probably point out here is that 立ち去れた means (someone) was able to leave.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  And thanks for the correction of my grammar.