# What does いきやすい say here?

Tags: grammar

The following is an excerpt from a dialogue between me and my language partner. We talked about movies deviating in certain points from the original works they are derived from (e.g. Lord of the rings books vs. movies), and how this can have both its pros and cons.

For context, I will include the full block of her reply concerning this point:
パディントンの映画は原作（げんさく：元の作品のことをこう言います）とは違いますが、ファミリーで楽しめるエンターテインメントになっていて、とても良かったです。
ロード・オブ・ザ・リングも、日本語に翻訳された本の方（『指輪物語』）は、とても長く、難しいので、子どもが読み切るのはなかなか難しいです。映像の場合、エルフとドワーフがどう違うか、一目でわかるので、一緒に観ている息子に説明しなくても済みます。目と耳から情報が入ってくるので、話に入っていきやすいのではないかと思います。

The sentence in question:
目と耳から情報が入ってくるので、話に入っていきやすいのではないかと思います。

My attempt at translation:

"Because the information enters from eyes and ears, I wonder if while one enters the story it isn't the easy way?"

So first, I interpreted the combination of ではないかと思います as way to say "I wonder if...(isn't)?". I don't know if that's legit, I just couldn't come up with something which would make more sense. 
Second I parsed 話に入っていきやすい as 話に入って and いきやすい. An alternative I can think of would be to read it as 話に入りやすい and 話に行きやすい. However, this feels a bit redundant, because one would basically say the same thing twice "easy to enter" and "easy to go (there)". Furthermore, chosing this option I can't think of a translation which wouldn't sound pretty wrong.

I'm also not sure wether I should interprete いき in いきやすい as a noun or as a verb, and wether that would actually matter or not^^ I know the verb+やすい/にくい pattern, for example: この料理は食べにくいです。=> "This meal is hard to eat" (probably because it tastes awful...^^). I don't know if the meaning would change by any means if I regarded 食べ as a noun or verb here, and considering what I've learnt about derivation in japanese so far, I guess the verbs ます-stem is regarded as a noun anyway in such cases, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- 話に入る (lit. "to enter a story") in this context means "to devote oneself into the story."
- This いく is a **subsidiary verb** explained [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/676/5010), so please don't separate it from 入って. It slightly adds the nuance of "over a period of time" or "away from here (the real world)", but I think it doesn't have to be translated. This can even be dropped without largely changing the meaning of the sentence.
- いき before やすい is a masu-stem of a *verb*. I don't think a noun can precede にくい/やすい in the first place. You said you already know the [～やすい pattern](http://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n4-grammar-%E3%82%84%E3%81%99%E3%81%84-yasui/), but your textbook didn't tell you to translate it as "the easy way", did you?
- ～のではないか (literary/formal) or ～んじゃないか (casual) is just a way of saying things mildly and unobtrusively.

So 話に入っていきやすいのではないかと思います is roughly the same as 話に入りやすいと思います, "(If there is video,) I think it's easier to dive into the story."