# The use of strategy/戦略 in this line

Tags: translation

I have the following line of dialogue

> されに視野を広げた「戦略」によっては戦いそのものの意味すら変わってくる

Two people have been talking about the changes needed to get to grips with potential future tech that might disrupt the currently established ways things are done. They might need to switch to more dangerous weapons and such.

I have a problem with above line because while 戦略 is supposed to mean strategy, it kinda IMO doesn't fit there. I get the impression this person is talking about something she read/heard about people who were looking at the big picture and have found that the meaning of fighting has changed/has been changing. But that's not excatly what is said here. So what would be your interpretation.

Changed/changing is also the issue. I think the normal translation of 変わってくる would be that the change has happened and this new state of affairs has been happening to now and will continue. But in context that doesn't exactly make sense, because change is supposed to happen in future. The only interpretation that would fit would be that this means that the process of change has (already) started happening in the past and is still happening now. So what would be the correct interpretation here?

Comment: To confirm, are you interpreting "によって" as "according to" (Please let me know if I'm totally off!)? That's what I'm reasoning based on the content of your post ("talking about something she read/heard"). However, here it means "by means of the ('big picture' strategy)" or "because of the presence and significance of the ('big picture' strategy)". Perhaps that might help.

Comment: @Otomatonium Yeah. I have been interpreting the first bit to mean something along the lines of "according to strategy/es with long/wide view/that opened my eyes".
How would your work?
"Because (some) strategy opened my eyes, the meaning of fighting itself (has for me?) changed"? That's still not entirely good.

Comment: 視野を広げた doesn't refer to the speaker's view of things, but instead means that the strategy itself covers a wider range of things than before, and so therefore is a game-changer (i.e., changing the meaning of "戦い). I can see how 視野を広げた can be interpreted to mean the speaker's point of view, but a small cue is the absence of an explicit owner of 視野. The owner of 視野 here is ambiguous, so we have to determine it from context, so it's probably the range of the strategy itself, or perhaps the company/organization implementing it.

Comment: The trouble here is that this is first and LAST time strategy is mentioned here. Also there hasn't really been any changing of the meaning of fighting...
Could it be something like:
"Because of this (new) far reaching strategy, even the meaning behind fighting is changing"?
Because that might make some sense. stragegy here would be the possible change in weaponary as a response to another tech and it all is changing for why they fight and such.

Comment: 変わってくる means that change will happen in the future, so the change hasn't happened yet. In other words the "game" hasn't yet changed, but it will because of the wider scope the new strategy addresses. If you want to say change has happened and will continue to happen, you can say 変わっている、変わりつつある、変わり続けている, etc.

Comment: It can be taken as future? I mean that makes more sense but I thought kuru implied the state coming here since it's comming. And this: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/676/difference-between-%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%8F-and-%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8B
But sure, if you say so.

Comment: @Otomatonium Also, how about making a proper answer so I can mark it as the answer?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll make one once we're in agreement that ～てくる is a future tense expression:https://books.google.com/books?id=l-C4H2sBJlEC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA120&hl=en#v=onepage&q&f=false (referenced in  japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/676/)

Comment: @Otomatonium I see now: https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/helping-verbs/#3 . Kuru un future means something will kinda catch up with us. So the strategy will be changing the meaning of fighting and come to us. Might kinda surprise us. Or change will come.

Comment: By the way, is the first expression in the sentence supposed to be 「さらに」?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

> 視野を広げた「戦略」によっては

This means "due to the strategy, with an increased scope,"

> 戦いそのものの意味すら変わってくる

This means "even the definition of 'fighting' will come to change"

> 変わってくる

This is future tense, meaning "will come to change" https://books.google.com/books?id=l-C4H2sBJlEC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA120&hl=en#v=onepage&q&f=false

### In essence

The new strategy with a wider scope will be a game-changer.