# What is the conjugation form, grammar of もうすぐ込んできそう ？

Tags: grammar, conjugations, subsidiary-verbs, aspect, auxiliaries

> アナウンス：皆様、本日はご来場ありがとうございます。午前十時現在の各館の
>   混雑状況と催しものの お知らせをいたします。まず、ロボット館はただいま、
>   一時間待ちとなっております。ロボット館のレ ストランではロボットがランチ
>   をお席までお運びをするサービスをしております。お昼近くになります と、さ
>   らに混雑が見込まれます。次に、未来館は現在すぐにお入りいただけます。なお、
>   未来館では一 時と三時に映画上映がございます。それから、化石館は現在 5 分
>   程度の待ち時間でお入りになれますが、 11 時から恐竜ショウがございますので、
>   そろそろ混雑が始まることが予想されます。また、歴史館の待 ち時間は 30 分程
>   度となっております。歴史館は会場が広いため、見学にお時間がかかります。余
>   裕を 持っておいでください。
>
> 男：結構込んでるね。効率的に見ないと、全館回れないよ。どこからみる？
>
> 女：映画は絶対に見逃せないから、時間に遅れないようにしようね。
>
> 男：ふん、分かった、分かった。じゃあ、それまで、どうする？レストランに行
>   く？面白そうだし。
>
> 女：並んでる時間がもったいないよ。きっと、お昼すぎたら、空くんじゃない？
>   食べるのは遅くなって もいいよ。ええっと、恐竜ショウも今から一時間後か。
>
> 男：でも、今ならあまり待たないで入れるし、ショウ以外に見るものもあるんだ
>   から。もうすぐ**込んできそうだし**、その前に行って見ちゃおうよ。ショウは無
>   理して見なくてもいいし。
>
> 女：そうだね。じゃ、その後は映画ね。

source: http://japanesetest4you.com/pdf/n1-listening-7.pdf

***Question***

From this conversation, I understand that 込んできそうだし means something like, it seems like it's going to be crowded soon.

But what is the grammar structure of  込んでき? What is the conjugation form being used here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you've missed the subsidiary verb くる? Here's the breakdown:

- こんで: te-form of the godan intransitive verb こむ, "to be crowded"
- き: masu-stem (pre-masu form) of the subsidiary verb くる, "(gradually) over time"

  - [Difference between -ていく and -てくる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/676/5010)
- そう(だ): "to seem; to look like"
- し: conjunction for marking a reason, "because"