# Trouble understanding 着ていったら

Tags: grammar

I am having trouble understanding 着ていったら in the following sentence:

明日の夕食会にはどんな服を着ていったら良いですか。

I understand how ~たら is normally used, its more combination with ていっ that seems to be throwing me off.

How is this different from using 着たら ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between -ていく and -てくる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/676/difference-between-%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%81%8f-and-%e3%81%a6%e3%81%8f%e3%82%8b)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 明日の夕食会にはどんな服を**着ていったら**良いですか。

着ていったら is the たら form (conditional form) of 着て行く, "wear and go".
(着て is the て form of the verb 着る. いったら is the たら form of [行]{い}く.)

The sentence is literally like...
"To the dinner party tomorrow, what should I wear and go?"
→ "What should I wear to go to the dinner party tomorrow?"

Comment: Awesome, that makes perfect sense. Thank you.