# Verb てform + くる what does it mean?

Tags: grammar, て-form, subsidiary-verbs

I'd like to know what is the meaning of the previous pattern I mentioned in the following sentence:

> 職場ではそんな話ばかりきこえてくるぞ！

I guess きこえて is the てform of 聞こえる.
But what is the meaning of きこえて + くる and what does exactly that ぞ mean?

I really hope you can help with this.
助けてください

Comment: have you tried looking up the grammar principle?  https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/helping-verbs/

Comment: Related: [Difference between -ていく and -てくる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/676/78)

Answer (score 3):

Kikoete kuru means that you overhear something or hear it unintentionally. The "kikoeru" part means that you can hear it, and the "kuru" means the sounds or speech come to you without making a special effort to listen.

Kaeru no uta ga kikoete kuru yo = I hear the sound of frogs.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RCyricRc_Ds

> what does exactly that ぞ mean?

Ending particle indicating assertion of a statement, roughly the same as "yo".

Comment: Not sure why this answer is downvoted (even if there's a room for considering "without making a effort").

Comment: @user4092 - this site has a problem with serial/revenge downvoting, which doesn't seem to be being dealt with by the stackexchange software, so presumably it's coming from a moderator or some other trusted user to whom the "revenge downvoting" prevention is not applied.

Answer (score 0):

「てくる」can mean that someone goes somewhere and comes back with a direction verb such as:

```
マクドナルドに行ってくる。 I will go to McDonalds and come back
```

But it can also mean that someone did something before coming physically to where they currently are, although it sounds strange in English:

```
食べてきました。
I ate (before coming here).
見てきました。
I saw it (before coming here).
ついに、その時がやって来ました。
Finally, that time came (and is here)
帰ってきました。 
I came home (and am now here at home)
```

It can also mean that they have "come to" start doing something.

```
分かってきました。
I came to understand.
英語を話せるようになってきました。
I came to be able to speak English.
```

I believe in your example sentence, 聞こえてくるぞ describes how the person goes to work and hears about a certain topic of conversation all the time before, presumably, coming home.

Comment: I don't think that the "kuru" is related to coming home. How can that theory explain the kikoete kuru in the song I mentioned in my answer?