# Semantic classification of verbs

Tags: verbs, て-form, semantics

Lately, I've been spending a lot of focus in how to translate certain verbs in the form ～ている. Mostly comes from the fact that, depending on the verb, it can have a meaning of prolonged action (e.g. 食べている, I'm eating) or the result of a change of state (e.g. 結婚している, I'm married).

This is fairly easy for certain common verbs, but it gets complicated for others (especially when certain verbs can take both stances, e.g. 分かる). For all of those experiencing the same problem, I was glad to have found the fairly well known book `A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar`. On its second annex, it features a detailed classification of each type of verb, along with plenty of examples (images of the annex bellow).

[image: Verb classification pg 1]
[image: Verb classification pg 2]
[image: Verb classification pg 3]

Unfortunately, this is just a small list of the most common Japanese verbs. I searched the internet for a more extensive list, but couldn't find it.

Therefore, I wanted to know if someone knows of an extensive list of verbs classified in this manner. I know that this has all the flags to be an "open question" but I feel like it's something fairly important to completely understand the ～ている form. I'm a bit surprised I didn't find much info on this though. [Jisho](https://jisho.org/) does not classify the verbs in this manner. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_grammar) explains each classification but does not provide an extensive list. Most other guides (e.g. [sci.lang.japan](https://www.sljfaq.org/afaq/afaq.html), [An Introduction to Japanese Syntax, Grammar & Language](http://pomax.github.io/nrGrammar/) and [Tae Kim's Guide to Learning Japanese](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar)) don't seem to mention this either.

Am I the only one finding this classification useful and craving for more?

Note: This classification is unrelated with 一段 and 五段 classification present in posts like [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9624/whats-the-difference-between-ichidan-godan-and-ru-u-verbs-classification) and [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1348/verb-classifications-by-japanese-learners).

Comment: Many (most?) verbs work both as a punctual verb and a continual verb depending on the context (e.g. [送っている](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3122/5010), 溶けている, [寝ている](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/57193/5010), [入っている](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/78612/5010), 来ている, 読んでいる...) You would find lots of exceptions just for verbs contained in this small list.

Comment: Yeah, and pretty much all verbs allow for an experiential reading for 〜ている (it can be forced with adverbs like 今までに三回) that essentially reads like the perfective. It’s hard to not get that mixed up. I find that a decent test of verb category is 1時間+past tense, like “1時間走った” or “1時間泳いだ” vs “*1時間ついた” or “*1時間起きた”. Just realize that that category doesn’t fully determine its behavior in all contexts.

Comment: It would be nice if there was some kind of dictionary that had little symbols for these in the entries or something. Or a specific collection of examples noting the different categories for various verbs.

Comment: English has a similar classification for item A through E, and I'd be happy to see such a list for English verbs, too.

Comment: So in the meantime, all we go by is the context of the sentence and our experience with the language, right?