# Is「していこう」another way to write「移行する」

Tags: verbs, conjugations

> 人間はみな平等だよね、そういう社会にしていこうね

I think this quote means something along the lines of transitioning into a society in which everyone is equal, but if that is an accurate translation, then why is していこう not 移行する?

So, is this a proper way to write suru verbs? If it is, then how does it change the sentence? Or maybe even I'm just off on the translation and していこう isn't even supposed to be 移行する at all?

Comment: Isn't it just the volitional form of していく?

Comment: Are you familiar with the grammar point 〜にする?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

移行する is not used in this sentence. It's the te-form of [～にする](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%AA-adjective-%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-ni-suru-meaning/) ("to make [something] ～") followed by the [subsidiary verb 行く](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/676/5010) ("gradually", "over time") in its volitional form. A very literal translation would be "Let's (gradually) make (our society) such a society."