# 駅まで遠いですから、歩いていくので - は疲れますよ or 疲れていますよ。

Tags: meaning

> 駅まで遠いですから、歩いていくのでは
>
> 1. 疲れますよ
> 2. 疲れていますよ。

I chose 2 above but it was wrong, 1 - は疲れますよ is the correct answer.

My interpretation and reasoning: "The station is far from here so, I walked and therefore I am currently tired"

So with my translation then 2 should be correct, it is currently happening, I am currently tired because the station was far, why is 2 wrong and 1 correct?

Comment: Do you understand how では works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you saw ので ("because") in the sentence? Then no, this sentence does not have one. This の after 歩いていく is a plain nominalizer, and you have misinterpreted (or ignored) では.

`noun + では` [has many usages](https://selftaughtjapanese.com/2015/02/26/japanese-particle-combination-%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF-de-wa-and-%E3%81%98%E3%82%83-ja/), but here it roughly means "With X" in the sense of "If X is used/chosen".

- スマホでは画面が小さすぎます。
  (lit.) With a smartphone, the screen is too small.
  The screen is too small if you used a smartphone.
- これでは買えません。
  With this (amount of money), I cannot buy it.
- 毎日外食するのではお金が沢山かかります。
  If you choose to eat out every day, it costs a lot of money.
  <sub>(This の is a nominalizer.)</sub>

Also note that 歩いていく is in the present tense, and this [-ていく](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/676/5010) implies someone moves **from here** (to the station).

Therefore you have to read the first half of the sentence like this:

> 駅まで遠いですから、歩いていくのでは
>
> Because the station is far from here, if one (chooses to) walk (from here to) there,...

And naturally, the correct choice is 2.

"I walked (from the station) so I am tired" would be 歩いて**きた**ので疲れています. (There is no は after で, くる is used instead of いく, and くる is in the past form)