# What does "ふってきて mean in the sentence "これが、突然空からふってきて..."?

Tags: verbs, て-form, particle-が, subsidiary-verbs

I know the sentence means something like "This suddenly came out of the sky...".

"これが" means "this is" (side question: why add "が" instead of just keeping it as "これ"?)

"突然空" means "suddenly" and "sky"

"から" means "from"

But I'm not sure what "ふってきて" means. Is it a variation of "ふる"?, if so, why alter it?

Comment: Can you include more context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

降って【ふって】きて is the te-form of 降る followed by [the subsidiary verb (-て)くる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/676/5010) in its te-form. くる as a subsidiary verb is very common in Japanese, so you have to get used to it.

- 降る: "to fall; to move down"
- 降って: te-form of 降る
- 降ってくる: "to fall (toward me); to come down"
- 降ってきて: te-form of 降ってくる "to fall (toward me) (and...)"

が is not "is" but a generic subject marker. が is used simply because これ is the subject of the sentence.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your comment was very helpful!