# ～てくる meaning for 意志動詞

Tags: grammar, meaning, business-japanese

Please what is the use of "～てくる" in that sentence? I have been struggling to understand it

> 一気にその日中にA社B社C社から借りていくそういう方法取ってくるのでお金はその場で回収しちゃう

By the way it came out in this video at 29:54 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bvgHpCGkbZ0&t=1794s

Comment: You should include who is saying it about whom to get a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

This (-て)くる is used to express someone is (either psychologically or physically) coming closer to the speaker. See: [Difference between -ていく and -てくる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/676/5010)

If it's a physical movement, the part in question is simply "they take such-and-such a means before visiting me/us" or "they come to me/us after taking such-and-such a means". If it's a psychological movement, くる indicates そういう方法 is how those people "approach" or "try to deal with" the speaker.

Answer (score 0):

"そういう方法取ってくる" would mean "they shall take such tricky ways" (for raising enough amount of cash) like "borrowing from multiple lenders in short time" so, this sentence is suggesting "when they take that move, we will collect all money immediately as a counter move (to avoid damages from their tricky move.)"

Comment: `when they take that move, we will collect all money` でもビデオを観たところ、「そういう方法を取る」のも「お金はその場で回収しちゃう」のも詐欺犯罪者側ですよ？

Comment: なるほど…そうなんですね。どういう手口なんでしょうね。

Comment: So I conclude that "てくる" doesn't have a significant meaning in this context ?

Comment: I suppose so. There is no significant difference if we paraphrase this as "そういう方法取るから" but there serms to be  some small nuance of future and assumption added.