# What does てくる mean in this sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning

> 私のベッドに寝転がっていた仙台さんが当然のように言って、肩を叩い**てくる**

I know the general grammar behind it meaning change of state and movement but its my first time seeing it with a verb like 叩く

Comment: This might be nitpicking but are you asking about てくる, not ってくる? The quotated sentence doesn't include ってくる.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

てくる can be used also with something that is *psychologically* getting closer to the observer. In this case, the physical distance traveled (from the bed to 私) may be almost zero, but the act of 叩く itself is something that affects you psychologically, and that's why くる fits.

See: [Difference between -ていく and -てくる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/676/5010)

> 来る is for something that moves towards the speaker (not necessarily a physical movement), or towards another person's viewpoint that the speaker adopts.